# How can I scale Platform Events to actually be useful?

Tags: platform-event

I have an LWC app I'm building with approximately 200 users, expected to grow to 400 over the next few years, so mid-size as far as Salesforce customers goes, I assume. We need the client side to get notified of one particular database update. If the status for a record gets updated, the UI for users may need to get updated. Perhaps the status requires that the sort order change, perhaps it requires that the record be removed from a datatable or added to a datatable.

Platform Events seems to be the natural tool for this. My client has an Unlimited license, which by default allocates 1.5 million delivered events per month according to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm).

The current system we're replacing tracks status changes, and there are approximately 1,000 status changes per day. 1,000 changes times 200 users 30 days is 6 million events per month, beyond even the 4.5 million that we could theoretically upgrade to with an add-on. And we expect that to double within a few years.

Ideally we'd like users to be updated on all record updates, but given the limits we decided to try just on the most important field, the status field, but even that will generate events far beyond the allocation.

Is this possible with Salesforce. Given a limit of 1.5 million events, how can large corporations use this feature in any way that is actually helpful? Is there another Salesforce technology that I'm unaware of that can help?

Comment: AFAIK allocation for high-volume PEs can be increased beyond documented limits - talk to your account exec. That said, your event doesn't have to be a CometD-based event. One solution architecture: deliver the event to an on-platform non-CometD subscriber such as an Apex trigger, no allocation limit here. Then callout to an external service or write to a custom object in SF. The latter is a derivation that enables a performance-optimized poll from your client.  Take a look at [Event-Driven](https://architect.salesforce.com/design/decision-guides/event-driven) decision guide for more options.

Comment: New [Pub/Sub API](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/07/pub-sub-api-building-event-driven-integrations-just-got-even-easier) might alleviate some of the performance/allocation issues. When it ships, that is.

Comment: The custom object suggested by @identigral could be a Big Object : you keep 1 million (free) for a while, then archive off-site or delete them.

Comment: Would the pub/sub API be good for this? You can have a middleware system subscribe to change data capture events, platform events, whatever, and then do whatever is necessary from there. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/07/pub-sub-api-building-event-driven-integrations-just-got-even-easier

Comment: Orgs can have max 50k events handled by a CometD subscriber / 24 hours too, completely unusable in enterprise scenarios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is through **Polling**. Polling is a technique where we check for fresh data over a given interval by periodically making API requests to a server.

In LWC use **setInterval** to fetch fresh data from Apex in regular intervals (say 1 or 5 minute(s))

Comment: That's actually a direction we're considering, but we're worried about an order of magnitude more events (in a generic sense). We want the data to be nearly live, 200 users, every 10 seconds, 72,000 polls per hour, not sure if we'll run into other problems with that. And isn't Platform Events built precisely to prevent the need for polling?

Comment: I would think that [empApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) was what you need here, using Change Data Capture. The point is, the streaming is only active while the relevant page is open.

Comment: We did some tests with `empApi` and found that a single event sent resulted in our allocation dropping once for each client, meaning we're looking at 6 million delivered events, far beyond Platform Event allocation.

Comment: This is what we ended up doing.

Answer (score 1):

In a past project, we simply connected an Enterprise Service Bus (ESB) to Salesforce as a subscriber, then connected all of our other clients to this ESB. Conceptually, you should be able to either locate an ESB you can subscribe to, or roll your own ESB with your favorite hosting platform, set up your Content Security Policy (CSP) in Salesforce to allow access to the host, and then just have your clients connect with the appropriate APIs. I do not generally give product recommendations, but simply searching for a Salesforce-enabled ESB system should net you some results.

Comment: Probably worth expanding the acronym here. If I'm lost, I can imagine many others who come across this answer will be, as well.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Fair enough. I was tired when I wrote that up.